# "Vidalia detected that the Tor software exited unexpectedly."

Tags: proxy, tor

I can start and kill tor via command line, but I want to control it with Vidalia. The browser bundle works, but I'd rather not use it. This is the message log in vidalia:

```
Sep 25 19:29:13.696 [Notice] Tor v0.2.3.22-rc (git-4a0c70a817797420) running on Linux.
Sep 25 19:29:13.696 [Notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 25 19:29:13.696 [Notice] Read configuration file "/home/brian/.vidalia/torrc".
Sep 25 19:29:13.697 [Notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.16-stable using method epoll (with changelist). Good.
Sep 25 19:29:13.697 [Notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 25 19:29:13.697 [Warning] /var/run/tor is not owned by this user (brian, 1000) but by debian-tor (114). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Sep 25 19:29:13.697 [Warning] Before Tor can create a control socket in "/var/run/tor/control", the directory "/var/run/tor" needs to exist, and to be accessible only by the user account that is running Tor.  (On some Unix systems, anybody who can list a socket can connect to it, so Tor is being careful.)
Sep 25 19:29:13.698 [Notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 25 19:29:13.698 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Sep 25 19:29:13.698 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: Its permission issue. Have you tried running vidalia with su. `gksu vidalia` ?

Comment: the currently packaged version of tor works fine.  i suspect you used a binary installer or compiled from source.

Comment: @sagarchalise: **Don't run tor as root!** That would compromise your computer if a remote exploit is found in Tor.

Answer (score 1):

@Mechanical snail:
To start tor manually in Debian (or ubuntu I guess) I would recommend using: `sudo service tor start` or if you are in a graphical environment like Gnome or KDE you can use `gksudo service tor start` and even make a shortcut for that in the applications menu. That way you are independent of any changes in the internals of the tor package, e.g. a change in the user name or so. And you can stop tor from within Vidalia as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the line

```
Sep 25 19:29:13.697 [Warning] /var/run/tor is not owned by this user (brian, 1000) but by debian-tor (114). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
```

You're running it as the wrong user. The Tor package for Ubuntu (from torproject.org; see https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) is supposed to be run as the `debian-tor` user (for security reasons, by separating the Tor process from your user's files and programs).

Since the control socket is owned by `debian-tor` rather than your user, your `tor` process fails to bind to it, hence the error. When Tor startup fails, Vidalia gives the "exited unexpectedly" error message.

If you want to start Tor manually, try `sudo -u debian-tor tor`.